# how do i retrieve image from database from the code i am using?

Tags: php, html, mysql

hi i have already typed my code below. the database is saving the path of image but it is not displaying the image . where could i be wrong?

```
<div class="profile">
    <?php
    if (isset($_FILES['profile']) === true) {
        if (empty($_FILES['profile']['name']) === true) {
            echo 'Please choose a file';
        } else {
            $allowed = array('jpg', 'jpeg', 'gif', 'png');
            $file_name = $_FILES['profile']['name'];
            $file_extn = strtolower(end(explode('.', $file_name)));
            $file_temp = $_FILES['profile']['tmp_name'];
            if (in_array($file_extn, $allowed) === true) {
                ///upload file.
                change_profile_image($session_user_id, $file_temp, $file_extn);
            } else {
                echo 'incorrect file type. Allowed formats: ';
                echo implode(', ', $allowed);
            }
        }
    }
    if (empty($user_data['profile']) === false) {
        echo '<img src"', $user_data['profile'], '"
                    alt="', $user_data['first_name'], '\'s">';
    }
    ?>
    <form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <input type="file" name="profile">
        <input type="submit">
    </form>
</div>
```

and the function change_profile_image I am calling is below:

```
function change_profile_image($user_id, $file_temp, $file_extn) {
    $file_path = 'images/profile/' . substr(md5(time()), 0, 10) . '.' . $file_extn;
    //echo $file_path;
    move_uploaded_file($file_temp, $file_path);
    mysql_query("UPDATE `users` SET `profile` = '" 
          . mysql_real_escape_string($file_path) 
          . "' WHERE `user_id` = " 
          . (int) $user_id);
}
```

the database is saving the image path but not displaying the image on the webpage.

Comment: Forgive me, but where are you actually trying to display the photo?

Comment: `echo '<img src"', $user_data['profile'], '"` should be `echo '<img src="', $user_data['profile'], '"` for a start.

Comment: Why a simple image change code has to be so complicated?

Comment: @Chris re-read what you commented

Comment: @LuthandoLoot Indeed, I didn't realize there were more mistakes just on that line. I'm too late to edit my comment now, but I guess it should say: `echo '<img src"', $user_data['profile'], '"` should be `echo '<img src="'.$user_data['profile'].'"`

Comment: remove `===` expression from `isset` and `empty`. Those functions always return boolean value. Yo can simply write `if(isset($whatever)){}`. *This is a suggestion and not the answer*.

Comment: @sagarkodte that is very wrong code :)
@hardeep a part from Chris corretions, are you sure the path is correct? How and where are you creating `$user_data` variable?

Comment: @sagarkodte the code suggestion doesnt display anything.

Comment: @chris the code works. even mine with comma is ok the only thing i was not seeing was the assignment sign which i didnt include after img src. thanks all.

Comment: is this question still open/unsolved? @hardeep answer given but no green tick ;-)

Comment: @Fred-ii- i think in one of the comment i said the chris suggestion is working for me. think it is open still.

Comment: Then @Chris should post the comment as an answer in order to mark the question as closed/solved. If he doesn't want to, then I can post a community wiki quoting it. FYI: No rep is gained when an answer is posted as a community wiki.

Comment: @Fred-ii- I've posted my comment as an answer now. Sorry about that. I'm still learning about when it's appropriate to take a comment and make it an answer.

Comment: @Chris Right on Chris, *cheers*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Where you've written

```
echo '<img src"', $user_data['profile'], '"
```

change it to

```
echo '<img src="'.$user_data['profile'].'"
```

Note the added equals sign and that full-stops instead of commas are used for concatenation.

Comment: Chris; I don't find anything wrong with posting an answer from comments, when it comes from "your" own comment(s). It's the ones who feed off of other people's comment(s) for their own personal gain that isn't right. You've my vote here ;-) P.s.: I do it myself at times.

Comment: Good to know. Thanks @Fred-ii-.

Answer (score 1):

**First of all, I want to isolate some security issues...**

When you're uploading a file, the file extension should never be checked. You should simply check the file MIME like so:

```
class FileSecure
{
    public resource $Allowed;
    private object $Info;
    public function __construct($allow)
    {
        $this->Allowed = $allow;    
        $this->Info = new finfo();
    }
    public function Check($file) : bool
    {
        if(in_array($fileType = $this->Info->file($file, FILEINFO_MIME_TYPE, $this->Allowed))) { return true; } else { return false; }
    }
}
$fileCheck = array(
     'Image' => new FileSecure(['image/bmp', 'image/gif', 'image/jpeg', 'image/png']),
     'Text' => new FileSecure(['text/plain']),
     'Compressed' => new FileSecure(['application/zip', 'application/x-rar-compressed'])
);

// End of Class

($fileCheck['Image']->Check($_FILES['profile']['name']))? "" : die("Invalid image file..."); // make sure you delete the file if it is false
```

**Now back to the Question...**

Firstly, we cannot see what your file server so make sure that the file has saved where that path links too.

If it has, `var_dump()` your queries and ensure that it is the correct path with the correct extension and name.

Secondly, you have a lot of syntax issues which you could easily find yourself by enabling error reporting...

You can do this by: `error_reporting(1);`

Edit: Note, if you're storing the directory as the datetime (`substr(md5(time()), 0, 10)`) you will need to include this date into the database path so you know where it is.

Note: When using the `isset()` you don't need to match it to true or false, you can simple do:

```
// false
if(!isset($...))
{
}

// true
if(isset($...))
{
}
```